# PostgreSQL - privileges to get metadata of database

Tags: sql, postgresql, metadata, privileges

What **minimum** privileges my user needs to get metadata (name of tables, columns, functions, etc.) from database?

I need to select from:

```
[database].information_schema.schemata
[database].information_schema.columns
[database].information_schema.view_table_usage
[database].pg_catalog.pg_class
[database].pg_catalog.pg_namespace
[database].pg_catalog.pg_description
[database].pg_catalog.pg_proc
[database].pg_catalog.pg_index
[database].pg_catalog.pg_am
[database].pg_catalog.pg_attribute
[database].pg_catalog.pg_constraint
```

and for functions:

```
pg_get_viewdef()
pg_get_functiondef()
```

Comment: Related question of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315030/retrieving-all-object-privileges-for-specific-role

Comment: Based on some quick testing, zero permissions needed -- they're always available if you can connect. Better ask the question in the pg hackers list though, for confirmation.

Comment: @Denis it's not all true. Zero permissions needed for tables with prefix pg_% (or maybe I have on default some permisions?). But when I try select from information_schema.schemata it always returns 0 rows...

Comment: Right... And that's because the information schema is basically a bunch of views to access the catalog, assorted with calls to `pg_has_role()`. But you've still *select* privileges on the views.

Answer (score 0):

By default those have select access from public.  If you revoke public select access to the system tables, bad things happen (don't do that!).

For the information schema, you automatically have `select` privileges, but these are often filtered by what the user can actually see.