# Can I rely on the aclexplode() function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

There is a useful function in PostgreSQL 9.5 called `aclexplode()` but I can't seem to find any [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions.html) on it.

Should I avoid using it? Is it technically an unstable API?

Comment: I didn't find much for it either. Though, [from this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315030/retrieving-all-object-privileges-for-specific-role): that function is only handy for querying system information tables for permission details. For any other use I'd say it is not recommended. -- Also, [it has a backport](https://pgxn.org/dist/aclexplode/) for ancient versions as well.

Comment: What does it do? Maybe there is a different solution to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I am looking for an easy way to break out individual ACL privileges in `pg_database.datacl`. The `aclexplode()` function works great for this.

Comment: Postgres has over 2600 internal functions that are not officially documented. They are available and sometimes I use some of them. I see no reason why their use would be inappropriate. `aclexplode ()` is probably used to create `information_schema.table_privileges`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on it. This function is finally documented in upcoming PostgreSQL 12 ([commit](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=c62dd80cdf149e2792b13c13777a539f5abb0370)).

> `aclexplode` returns an `aclitem` array as a set rows. Output columns are grantor `oid`, grantee `oid` (`0` for `PUBLIC`), granted privilege as `text` (`SELECT`, ...) and whether the prilivege is grantable as `boolean`. `makeaclitem` performs the inverse operation.